# Do shared hosts grant access to INFORMATION_SCHEMAs?

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, information-schema

I was wondering if shared hosts generally grant access to this table to their users.

Would it be ok to rely on it to quickly get the current database structure from within a script?

My idea was to use this information to sanitize input lol. For example: `UPDATE table SET field = ?`

`?` can be a parameter (I'm using PDO), but what if I wanted to make `field` a variable to? Since PDO doesn't support that, I could use data from the info schema to find out if that column exists...

Comment: surly you would know the db structure if your putting data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any MySQL user will have access to `SELECT` on `information_schema`, owing to the fact that the user *must* be able to read `information_schema` to be able to read from databases to which he's been granted access.

You can test this out by creating a new user with only the `SELECT` privilege on a single table in a single database.  The user will be able to read anything in `information_schema` related to the granted tables in that database, but not anything which hasn't been granted.

```
/* Create a new user with only SELECT on one db: */
GRANT SELECT ON newdb.* TO newuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';

/* Login with that user and list databases */
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| newdb              |
+--------------------+
```

[From the relevant documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

> Each MySQL user has the right to access these tables, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges. In some cases (for example, the ROUTINE_DEFINITION column in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table), users who have insufficient privileges will see NULL.

Comment: you're saying that every select triggers another select from information_schema ?

Comment: @AnnaK. Access to `information_schema` is limited to grants the user has, but in order to be able to select cols from a table, the user must also be able to list those cols from information_schema.

Comment: @AnnaK. In other words, it isn't that a query "triggers" a query against information_schema, but when the query is compiled, information_schema must be consulted to validate it and validate user rights. For the user to be able to effectively use a MySQL client (which can list columns, their types, etc) all that is done by querying against information_schema.

Comment: @AnnaK. You may be able to make use of it. As mentioned in the docs, a user can query anything from information_schema related to objects he's been granted access to.